# Android : How do i use a local image as my background

Tags: android, background, local

I have a local image file that i want to use as an android app background, how do i do it?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Are you using appbuilder or writing it yourself? does your app have permissions to view files, have you tried googling that exact question?

Comment: By local, do you mean from your phone SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example
in main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/nameOfYourLocalFile"
android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Just put your `nameOfYourLocalFile.png` to `drawable` directory.
Hope its help.